# Adding delete items from recyclerView error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 29

And I guess it is because I have a function as a parameter of my Adapter, because if I comment that method it works, but I want to understand why its not working...

My adapter looks like this :

```
class MyAdapter(private val click: (position: Int) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var list = ArrayList<Int>()

    fun addItems(numberList: ArrayList<Int>) {
        list.addAll(numberList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun removeItemAt(position: Int) {
        list.remove(position)
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

    fun removeAll() {
        list.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false)
    )

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(list[position], position, click)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

       ....
        fun bind(number: Int, position: Int, click: (position: Int) -> Unit) {
          ...
            click.invoke(position)
        }
       ....

    }
}
```

The problem is when I set the adapter as follows :

```
adapter = MyAdapter { itemClicked ->
            //I'd like to delete the item so I have adapter.deleteItem(itemClicked)
        }
```

It crashes, but if I don't use that line of code it works without the click.

It's a simple app that I want to update the list, delete an item when clicking, and delete all the list if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is this...

your `removeItemAt` method in the Adapter uses `list.Remove(element: Int)` which refers to an actual element within the list, instead of `list.removeAt(position: Int)` which will actually delete the item by the position.

Answer (score 0):

notifyItemChanged(position: Int) -> is used for item changes(not deletes).

what the program doing?

let's say list items are (1, 2, 3, 4)

1) list.remove(position) is removing clicked item for example 2 (newList is 1, 3, 4)

2) notifyItemChanged(position) is assuming list item changed NOT DELETED. so it thinks 2 in the first list has changed to 3 but not deleted. But, actually you deleted it. As it thinks the size is 4, it throws indexOutOfBoundException

Conclusion: use notifyItemChanged(pos:Int) for data changes inside the item, and notifyItemRemoved(pos: Int) for item deletes.

There is nothing with your high-order function

Comment: if I un comment the high order function is says this : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling  even if I use notifyItemRemoved... I've debugged it and it tries to delete even if I don't click...

Comment: Nevermind on my viewHolder I didn't put the setonclicklistener on the item so it was always doing the click

Comment: Using notifyItemRemoved it removes from the list but then it adds the same item deleted, any idea?

Comment: you should submit new updated list by adapter.submitList(updatedList)

Comment: I'm trying to update the list, and I'm doing list.clear() list.addAll(newList) notifyDataSetChanged() but it's empty then

Comment: is "list" variable the one inside adapter? If it is the list in the activity, you should apply it to the list inside adapter not activity

Comment: I mean, on my adapter I have a getter for the list, so I get that List, and change some items, then I send it back to the adapter and what I want to do is replace the old list for the new one.

Comment: try to put setter for the list as well. public void setList(List<Int> newList){ list = newList; notifyDataSetChanged(); }

Comment: I was using the same reference to the list so when I was clearing one list the other was also cleared...

Comment: check the setter. it is better I guess. It is not good to modify list outside adapter. That's why from Google Team introduced Adapter.submitList() method.

Comment: can not find submitList()

Comment: I'm not modifying the list, is like a sort, I get the list, I do sort, and then I create a new list of it, and I do a replace

Comment: I am currently using kotlin. submitList() should be kotlin stuff or newer version of recyclerview. can you please share that part of your code? or why not just use setter? setter is safe.

Comment: Because, I used to accidentally change the reference

Comment: so you mean create a setter for the list and whenever I update the content I just set it?